# Battery indicator is showing "Service Battery" notification

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, notifications

I upgraded my macbook RAM, but after that when I switched on my MAC it showed my "Service Battery" indicator in battery menu. I installed Battery Health application and it showed following stats.

[image: Battery Stats]

Its showing my original battery charge is left at 26%. Does that means I need to change my battery and get a new one. My macbook is 15 inch early 2011 model.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Mac's battery hasn't reached its maximum cycle count, which for your model is 1000 cycles (see [Mac notebooks: Determining battery cycle count](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1519)):

[image: MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011) battery cycle count]

Other factors may decrease battery life, so double-check the battery condition in System Information.app:

1. Open `Apple menu`>`About This Mac`>`More Info…`
2. Press `System Report…`
3. On the left hand side select `Hardware`>`Power` and look for `Condition`:

   [image: Battery Condition: Normal]

Article [OS X Mountain Lion: Battery conditions](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11205) lists the possible conditions:

> **Normal**: The battery is functioning normally.
>
> **Replace Soon**: The battery is functioning normally but holds less charge than it did when it was new.
>
> **Replace Now**: The battery is functioning normally but holds significantly less charge than it did when it was new. You can
> continue to use the battery until you replace it without harming your
> computer.
>
> **Service Battery**: The battery isn’t functioning normally, and you may or may not notice a change in its behavior or the amount of charge
> it holds. Take your computer in for service. You can continue to use
> your battery before it’s checked without harming your computer.

Comment: mine is saying service battery. Does this means that I need to get it replaced?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You should get your battery replaced because it is getting faulty.